# Can't see conditional choices in Shiny mainPanel?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to let the user choose from various options but for some reason I don't see the options in my main panel:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Reminder to do X"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(
        inputId = "type",
        label = "Reminder Type",
        choices = c("Single Date Reminder" = "single",
                    "Multi Date Reminder" = "multi",
                    "From-To Reminder" = "from_to"),
        selected = "single", width = '100%'
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.source == 'single'",
        dateInput("single_date", "Enter the date for your reminder", value = Sys.Date())
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.source == 'multi'",
        dateRangeInput("multi_date_1", 
                       label = "Enter from to dates", 
                       start = Sys.Date(), 
                       end = Sys.Date() + 7,
                       autoclose = TRUE)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.source == 'from_to'",
        dateRangeInput("multi_date_2", 
                       label = "Enter from to dates", 
                       start = Sys.Date(), 
                       end = Sys.Date() + 7,
                       autoclose = TRUE)
      )
    )
  )
)

  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
```

Please advise how can I see the selected datepicker option? I am hitting the radio button but can't see the datepicker.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the wrong ID referencing. Your `inputiD` is `"type"` and in your `conditionalPanel()` you are referencing to "`source`". So change all `input.source` to `input.type` and it will work.

So your code looks like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Reminder to do X"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(
        inputId = "type",
        label = "Reminder Type",
        choices = c("Single Date Reminder" = "single",
                    "Multi Date Reminder" = "multi",
                    "From-To Reminder" = "from_to"),
        selected = "single", width = '100%'
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type == 'single'",
        dateInput("single_date", "Enter the date for your reminder", value = Sys.Date())
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type == 'multi'",
        dateRangeInput("multi_date_1", 
                       label = "Enter from to dates", 
                       start = Sys.Date(), 
                       end = Sys.Date() + 7,
                       autoclose = TRUE)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type == 'from_to'",
        dateRangeInput("multi_date_2", 
                       label = "Enter from to dates", 
                       start = Sys.Date(), 
                       end = Sys.Date() + 7,
                       autoclose = TRUE)
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
```

And the output:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've modified your code a bit and included one example of `airDatepickerInput()`. Therefore I've changed this part of your code

```
     conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type == 'multi'",
        dateRangeInput("multi_date_1", 
                       label = "Enter from to dates", 
                       start = Sys.Date(), 
                       end = Sys.Date() + 7,
                       autoclose = TRUE)
)
```

To this

```
 conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type == 'multi'",
        airDatepickerInput(
          inputId = "multiple",
          label = "Select multiple dates:",
          placeholder = "You can pick 3 dates",
          multiple = 3, clearButton = TRUE
        )
      )
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Note that if you also want to select the time, insert `timepicker = TRUE` inside `airDatepickerInput()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, definitely a typo!
Do you know how can I add date and time (with multiple option to choose multiple times and dates) widget? @Miha

Comment: You mean something like this: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/date-and-date-range.html

Comment: Nope @miha. I mean I need something like airDatepickerInput

Comment: Please see my updated answer if this is something in the right direction.

Comment: how can I reach you to show you the situation over zoom?

Comment: I have sent you an invite on LinkedIn, I want to show you what I need, it's not exactly what you've showed. We can update the answer with your help. @miha